# Umbraco 7 is not loading Member types

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have upgraded Umbraco 4.11 to Umbraco 7.1.8 successfully. Everything is working fine but when I tried to access Member Types in umbraco panel i am getting error.[image]

When I am checking the error details in Firebug it is following :

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An item with the same key has already been added.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Factories.MemberTypeReadOnlyFactory.GetPropertyTypes(MemberTypeReadOnlyDto dto, MemberType memberType, Dictionary`2 standardProps)\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Factories.MemberTypeReadOnlyFactory.BuildEntity(MemberTypeReadOnlyDto dto)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.RepositoryBase`2.GetAll(TId[] ids)\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Services.MemberTypeService.GetAll(Int32[] ids)\r\n   at umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.MemberType.get_GetAll()\r\n   at umbraco.loadMemberTypes.Render(XmlDocument& Tree)\r\n   at umbraco.loadMemberTypes.Render(XmlTree& tree)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Trees.ApplicationTreeExtensions.TryGetXmlTree(ApplicationTree appTree, String id, FormDataCollection formCollection)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Trees.ApplicationTreeExtensions.TryLoadFromLegacyTree(ApplicationTree appTree, String id, FormDataCollection formCollection, UrlHelper urlHelper, String currentSection)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Trees.LegacyTreeController.GetTreeNodes(String id, FormDataCollection queryStrings)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Trees.TreeControllerBase.GetNodes(String id, FormDataCollection queryStrings)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem mostly occurs when there duplicate fields in database. This duplication can created while updating database. Same case here, I was upgraded my Umbraco from version 4 to version 7.1.8. There was a third party plugin named nforum which was having membership types duplication problem. I solved this problem by going back to original version (4.11), Uninstall the nForum plugin and then update again on version 7.1.8.